# UITextfield in UICollectionviewcell's contentView doesn't register taps

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I've added a UITextfield on a UICollectionViewCell's ContentView, but tapping on the UITextfield doesn't do anything and the text field isn't registering any touches. Things I've double checked:

- Keyboard toggling is on
- The ContentView returns TRUE for UserInteractionEnabled

Aside from moving the text field to UICollectionViewCell's regular view (which works), are there any options to make the contentView solution work?

Comment: check your cell height ...

Comment: add ContentView.clipToBounds = true

Comment: @jawadAli the cell height is pretty large (each cell almost takes up the full screen). I set contentview.cliptobounds = true but then all of the subviews on the content view dissappeared.

Comment: sir its your cell height issue .... your contentView is not fully bound with your cell height thats why you are not getting tap event

Comment: textField should receive tap even its in contentView

Comment: your contentView all edges attached with your cell ? please check that

Comment: I did print(cell.contentView.frame) in collectionviewWillDisplayCell and I got (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 726.0) so the height seems to be okay...unless it changes after everything loads?

Comment: can you share screen via teams or skype

Comment: You were right - I made my contentView background blue and it still wasn't showing Blue, and I made contentView.frame = self.bounds and that didn't work either. But I was using layout constraints, so this time I made all of the anchors the same as view and then everything started working. Does the contentView need to have its dimensions set in general? I thought that would be done automatically

Comment: contentView should be pinned with your cell

Comment: so can i post it as answer ?

Comment: @jawadAli yes please post as an answer. Also - how do you pin content view with your cell? I just did: self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your cell height issue .... your contentView is not fully bound with your cell height thats why you are not getting tap event

textField should receive tap even its in contentView

check your contentView all edges attached with your cell

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

     contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
         contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
         contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
         contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
     ])
 }
```